# Convenience of CollectionProxy for has_one?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have an `Accounts` model, which have many `CreditCards` and has one `BillingInfo`.

In `CreditCards` controller I initialize with the help of `CollectionProxy`:

```
class CreditCardsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    credit_card = current_account.credit_cards.new(credit_card_params)

    ...
  end
end
```

However, this doesn't work with `has_one` association:

```
class BillingInfosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    billing_info = current_account.billing_info.new(billing_info_params)

    ...
  end
end
```

The reason is; calling `billing_info` on `current_account` does return `nil` rather than empty `CollectionProxy`, which results sending `new` on `nil` and exists with `NoMethodError`.

Is there a way to use `CollectionProxy` or something similar to keep using

```
current_account.billing_info.new(billing_info_params)
```

rather than something like

```
BillingInfo.new(billing_info_params.merge(account_id: current_account.id))
```

to initialize? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are trying too hard. Rails has this functionality built in, so you can do this all in your CreditCardsController. Read [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `current_account.build_billing_info` or `current_account.create_billing_info` which are methods added by the `has_one` association.

> When initializing a new `has_one` or `belongs_to` association you must use the `build_` prefix to build the association, rather than the `association.build` method that would be used for `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations. To create one, use the `create_` prefix.

See the [has_one association reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) for more about these methods and the other methods active record adds for you.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is ensure every account has_one billing_info
you can user `after_create` callback to create a account's billing_info

another one is get billing_info first

`billing_info = current_account.billing_info || current_account.build_billing_info
billing_info.assign_attributes(billing_info_params)`

Comment: Not a big fan of `after_` & `before_` ActiveRecord::Callbacks but thanks for the suggestion. :)